# Restricts multiple selection in a tableView with a stepper (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two viewControllers, the first with a simple stepper

```
@IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {

      restrictioNumber.text = String(sender.value)
    }
```

and the second with a tableView

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "CATEGORY_CELL"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        let rowIsSelected = selectedIndexPaths != nil && selectedIndexPaths!.contains(indexPath)
        cell.accessoryType = rowIsSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    let nearbySearchSegueIdentifier = "goToMcourse"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark


     /*   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: nearbySearchSegueIdentifier, sender: list[indexPath.row])  */
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        cell.accessoryType = .none

    }
```

in this tableView i can select multiple cells but i would like to make a limit in how many can be selected and this limit must be represented by the number set with the stepper in the previous viewController
[image]

How i can do this?

Comment: Not related but since you do have a struct or class as model, I recommend to add the selection state to the model rather than using a separate array. Add a property `var isSelected = false` in the model, in `cellForRow` write `cell.accessoryType = list[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none` and in `didSelect / didDeselect` get the model by the index path, change the `isSelected` property accordingly and call `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)`. And forget `selectedIndexPaths` completely.

Comment: @vadian ok thank you, but i do not understand how to create the model, can you give me a simple example?

Comment: From the line `list[indexPath.row].name` I can see that `list` must contain an array of a custom struct or class with a property `name`. In this struct/class just add the line I proposed.

Comment: @vadian ah ok i understand, thanks!